# create subdomain in centos 6

Tags: centos, virtualhost, subdomain, centos6

I'm trying to create a subdomain in my virtual server (it's a centOS). I have edited the httpd.conf file like this:

NameVirtualHost *:80

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/zend/
  <Directory "/var/www/html/zend"> 
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 
    AllowOverride All 
    Order allow,deny 
    Allow from all 
  </Directory> 
  ServerName zend.mydomain.es
</VirtualHost>
```

When I try www.mydomain.es it's work fine, but when I try zend.mydomain.es I get Server Not Found error.
Are there any other files i must configure for this to work?

Comment: Did you setup your subdomain in your dns settings? E.g. DNS manager on GoDaddy?

Comment: Also make sure you restart your httpd service after you make your change. E.g. `service httpd restart`

Answer (score 2):

You should also setup dns for the your subdomain and make sure subdomain is pointing to the correct ip

Also check ping if it is replying:

> ping zend.mydomain.es

If the IP is correct check both Apache logs (error.log and access.log).

Answer (score 0):

1. I would recommend verifying your DNS settings for the subdomain.
   E.g. If you are hosting with GoDaddy, I would recommend making sure
   you have an entry for your subdomain there and that the IP points to
   the same box.
2. Next, if you haven't yet, after you make your changes to httpd.conf
   you need to restart the httpd service for the changes to take
   affect. So try `service httpd restart`

Hopefully one of those helps solve your issue.